# Read IP Address using SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Working with an ASP.Net application where I would like to pull IPv4 information from a SQL database using SQLDataReader. When reading an IP from SQL the data type is binary and I am not sure the best way to handle this.

Since there is no method for SQLDataReader.GetIPAddress() it seems that I would need to use SQLDataReader.GetBytes()? Many examples online around how to do this however since getstring is very simple I am hoping there is another simpler way to use getbyte() or another method to bring in the IP.

```
    Do While SQLReader.Read()
        Dim lastcom As System.DateTime = SQLReader.GetDateTime(0)
        Debug.WriteLine(lastcom.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")) 
        Debug.WriteLine(SQLReader.GetString(1)) 
        Debug.WriteLine(SQLReader.GetBoolean(2)) 
        Debug.WriteLine(SQLReader.GetString(3)) 
        Debug.WriteLine(SQLReader.GetString(4)) 
        Label_IP = SQLReader.GetString(1)            
        Label_Model.Text = SQLReader.GetString(4)
   Loop
```

Comment: Are you attempting to convert this to C#? What is the IP Stored as in the database, I'm assuming it would be stored as a `String` so a `varchar` or `nvarchar` for instance.

Comment: No need to convert to c#.. I usually write in vb.net.. Getstring fails saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'." GetDataTypeName returns binary for the column but in the database the column only contains actual ipv4 address in a format similar to xx.xx.xx.xx.

Comment: I refuse to write Visual Basic, but retrieve as a `byte[]` and in C# you would simply do: `System.Text.Encoding.GetString(...)`.  So convert the `byte[]` back into a string value from the byte data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making some assumptions about how the IP address is stored in the database (and only supporting IPv4 addresses), but you could try something like this:

```vb
Dim ipAddr(3) As Byte
' Assuming that column #1 is your IP address column
Dim byteCount = SQLReader.GetBytes(1, 0, ipAddr, 0, 4)
If byteCount = 4 Then
    Label_IP.Text = New IPAddress(ipAddr).ToString()
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Expected 4 bytes for IP address")
End If
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!.. Also looked further and found some stored procedure on the sql side responsible for the binary conversion. Not sure why this is the case here but either way greatly appreciate the help !

Comment: @jewbacca Glad it helped.  Not sure what the stored procedure would do - [`IPAddress.GetAddressBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the byte array for an IP address.  You may also want to talk a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - voting on/accepting answers is the best way to say thanks. :-)